# Merging in powerquery

Tags: merge, powerquery

although i selected Full Join, i couldn't get the all rows from both tables.

how can i get all rows from both tables ? (all 12093 rows)

maybe another join type may help ?

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(#"Beton Irsaliye Kumulatif",{"Proje No & Adi", "Firma Kodu"},#"Beton Muhasebe Kumulatif",{"Proje No & Adi", "Hesap No"},"Beton Muhasebe Kumulatif",JoinKind.FullOuter)
in
    Source
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your merge **is** accounting for all your rows.* It's just that 4 of the rows in the first table don't have matches in the second table.

Here's a simple example of what is happening. Here, I have two tables: Table1 and Table2. Both have 10 rows. In fact, both are exactly the same.

[image]

If I choose to do a Full Outer join with these, using Col1 and Col2 for matching, I'll see this:

[image]

It tells me that 10 of the rows from the first table (Table1) match rows of the second table (Table2).

Now, if I change the last two rows of Table1 (specifically, the last two rows of Col2 of Table1) like this:

[image]

Then when I try to do a Full Outer join the same way, I'll see this:

[image]

Only 8 of the rows from the first table (Table1) match rows of the second table (Table2).

But when I continue with the merge, I'll see Table1's information in a table with Table2's matching information as embedded tables in column "NewColumn" of that table:

[image]

When I then expand "NewColumn", I see all the info from Table1, as before, and all matching info from Table2, as well as rows that don't have matches between the two tables.

[image]

All rows of both tables are accounted for.